# Unexpected Token U Ajax Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, express

I've been having a problem all day sending json data via ajax to Express. 
My ajax looks like this:

```
$('#saveClause').click(function () {
    var username = document.getElementById('postUserName').innerHTML;
    var clauseTitle = document.getElementById('modalTitle').innerHTML;
    var clauseDescription = document.getElementById('modalDescription').innerHTML;
    var clauseText = document.getElementById('modalText').innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/classes/updateAssignment",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            username: username,
            title: clauseTitle,
            description: clauseDescription,
            text: clauseText
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        complete: function () {
          console.log("complete");  
        }, 
        success: function () {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Process Error");
        }

    });
});
```

and my Express Classes routes looks like this:

```
router.post('/updateAssignment', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.username)
    console.log(req.body.title);
    console.log(req.body.description);
    console.log(req.body.text);
    res.type('json');
    res.send({
        some: JSON.stringify({
            response: 'json'
        })
    });


});
```

I issued a postman post request to the url with this JSON object:

```
{
    "username":"testing",
    "title":"123",
    "description":"j456",
    "text":"seven"
}
```

and Express logged all the details in the console just fine, so it must be a problem with my ajax request as it's giving me an unexpected token u error but I don't know what's causing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the views being rendered with express? If not, you have to specify the complete url int he ajax field (ie: localhost:PORT/classes/updateAssignment/) and allow cors. Also, can you copy paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Thew views are being rendered with express,
This is the exact error I'm getting:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at parse (L:\CSSE\SPUR2017\authentication\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15) etc.

Comment: Ok so this is a node error. The parser is not able to parse your body. The ajax is fine it seems. Did you add the proper json parse to your middleware? When using postman what headers did you send?

Comment: I did add the proper body parser in my middleware, I've made other data posts to the server before but with forms as opposed to an ajax call but it doesn't seem to work. I didn't send headers in Postman.

Comment: Ok try getting rid of content type json in the ajax call then

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: You mind if I make an answer? I a,m new to this community and i am trying to get some reputation :)

Comment: Yeah sure! I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: Ok i Posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `contentType: "application/json",`

If you used postman with no headers, most likely this is causing the parser to fail.